# Listview de imagens e quantidade - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, drawable

Seguinte, tenho 2 perguntas que se relacionam, então vou fazer em 1 tópico.

Bom, uso essa query pra retornar um list de strings com os nomes dos produtos.

```
public List<String> getMedico() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome FROM Armas Where Classe like 'médico' ORDER BY nome ASC", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

Quando clico em um item do list ele abre uma nova página de detalhes, que mostra todos os outros atributos do produto. Aí, nessa página, eu recupero a imagem passando como parâmetro o nome do item clicado.

```
 public byte[] getImage(String name) {
    byte[] data = null;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT imagem FROM Armas WHERE nome = ?", new String[]{name});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        data = cursor.getBlob(0);
        break;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}
```

Blz, isso funciona tranquilo.
Agora, o que eu preciso: 
Retornar um "list de imagens". Ao invés de retornar o nome, quero retornar as imagens e coloca-las em um listview. Só que não tenho ideia de como fazer. Mas blz, fazendo isso, leva a segunda questão: Quando estiver pronto, vai retornar 300 imagens de ± 15kb cada. No geral dá quase 4mb. Retornar esse tanto de imagem pode pesar na aplicação na hora de abrir essa tela? E se tiver 3 fragmentos retornando 300 imagens cada?

Ah, quero fazer em sqlite e não colocar em drawables pq além da imagem vai ter nome e descrição. Ou seria melhor colocar em drawables, colocar no sqlite só o caminho da imagem e retornar isso de alguma forma?

Answer (score 2):

Cara você poderia fazer primeiramente um Objeto DTO com os atributos nome e Imagem, salvos no SQLite. Nisso, para limitar, procura utilizar um SQL onde você limita os resultados por páginas, tipo:

```
SELECT nome, imagem FROM Armas Where Classe like 'médico' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 5, 10
```

Isso irá retornar 5 a partir do row 10. Quando você precisar de mais imagens, é só mudar o valor de 10 para 15, 20.. Leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016100/how-to-query-sqlite-for-certain-rows-i-e-dividing-it-into-pages-perl-dbi).

Como você irá utilizar um grande número de resultados, utilize um RecyclerView. Utilizando o Scroll Listener, você consegue recuperar mais resultados quando o usuário der scroll na lista. Leia sobre isso [aqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView).

E assim, quando o úsuário clicar em um item da lista, é só pegar o nome salvo no Objeto DTO e abrir o fragment.

Espero que isso te ajude, abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Não perca tempo tentando colocar imagens no SQLITE. Dá pra fazer, mas perde tipo 99% da resolução, tornando a imagem inútil. Ou você salva no drawable e insere o caminho no db, tipo R.drawable.img01 (que nada mais é que um int), ou sobe as imagens em algum servidor online e salva o link no db.
Em ambos os casos, terá que usar uma biblioteca para carregar as imagens, como o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), por exemplo. É bem simples de usar. Se estiver no adapter, ao inve´s de `imgView.setResource....`, faça `Glide.with(contexto).load(R.drawable.img1).into(imgView);` ou `Glide.with(contexto).load("www.meuserv.com/img01").into(imgView);`

Comment: Bom, atualmente to fazendo com sqlite, e como as imagens já são pequenas, não parece que perderam qualidade, mas não respondeu oq eu perguntei

Comment: A primeira pergunta: "Só que não tenho ideia de como fazer"
Resposta: "...terá que usar uma biblioteca para carregar as imagens, como o Glide, por exemplo. É bem simples de usar..."
A segunda pergunta: "Retornar esse tanto de imagem pode pesar na aplicação na hora de abrir essa tela?"
Resposta: "...Em ambos os casos, terá que usar uma biblioteca..."

Vai pesar e vai crashar o app. Vai ter que usar uma lib pra gerenciar carregamento de imagens.

Comment: Partindo, lógico, do princípio que você já tem um arrayList de strings com os links das imagens ou um array de int, que no caso seria o drawable.

Comment: Por isso eu disse pra salvar as imagens como strings (links de um servidor externo) ou como ints (que é o drawable) pra não ter dificuldades na hora da query. Eu acho perca de tempo inserir imagens diretamente no db, pq tem que converter e desconverter toda hora...

Answer (score 0):

Sobre imagens em bancos de dados:

Eu não recomendo salvar imagens dentro do banco de dados, por questões de performance de query e ficamos pouco limitados quando trabalhamos com mais resoluções - e como sabemos, os dispositivos tem recursos limitados.

Quando salvamos a imagem no banco, e precisamos recuperar, temos que nos preocupar em fazer a tradução de texto para imagem, e se quisermos incluir, surge a mesma necessidade.
Recomendo sempre o uso da pasta de cache do app ('`/data/data/br.com.seuapp/images`') - `external storage` - para isso você pode fazer o upload das imagens dinamicamente, usando seu app para buscar no servidor.

Existe uma página do Android Developer (Google) que aborda como [exibir imagens de forma eficiente](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), nesta página você pode ler um pouco sobre como fazer processamento, manuseio e exibição de bitmaps.

**Lembrando que:** Se batermos uma foto em uma resolução de: 5 megapixels  (2592x1936 pixels), e quisermos carrega-la/exibir, utilizaremos ao todo, 19mb, estourando o limite de pré-carregamento de muitos dispositivos.