# Custom Listview com Picasso

Tags: android, listview

Bom galera, já fiz esse tópico~>[Listview de imagens e quantidade - Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180096/listview-de-imagens-e-quantidade-android/180100?noredirect=1#comment372859_180100)

Me deram algumas dicas e agora tô refazendo ele como me falaram.

Fiz um custom adapter para o listview.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String nome;
    private final Integer imagem;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String nome, Integer imagem) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_picasso, nome);
        this.context = context;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_picasso, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);

        txtTitle.setText(nome);
        Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(imagem)
            .into(imageView);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Aqui é onde tento usar:

```
public class PicassoTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picassotest);

        DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).open();
        List<String> names = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getTest();
        DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();

        ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lista);

        CustomAdapter adapter =  new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), names)
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

E essa é a query:

```
public List<String> getTest() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome, imagem FROM skin", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

Os problemas:
No custom `Adapter` nessa linha:

```
super(context, R.layout.list_picasso, nome);
```

da o erro 
    'cannot resolve method super(Activit, int, string)'

e na `PicassoTest`:

```
CustomAdapter adapter =  new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), names);
```

O `context` e nome não retorna, só a imagem.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A razão dos erros.

Primeiro aquele a que se refere o erro:

> cannot resolve method super(Activit, int, string)

`super` refere-se ao construtor da classe herdada, neste caso a um ArrayAdapter.
[ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) não ter nenhum construtor com essa assinatura.

Segundo, está a instanciar CustomAdapter com apenas 2 argumentos

```
new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), names)
```

enquanto declara o construtor com 3

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String nome, Integer imagem)
```

Além de que está a passar argumentos do tipo Context e List quando são esperados, nos dois primeiros parâmetros, os tipos Activity e String.

### Como resolver.

Pelo que eu entendi, o que pretende é:

- Apresentar uma lista de nomes com as respectivas imagens
- Os nomes e o *url* da imagem estão no banco de dados.
- O Adapter é responsável por obter as imagens usando a Api Picasso.

Primeiro é necessário ter uma classe que encapsule o nome e o *url*:

```
public class Skin{

    private String nome;
    private String url;

    public Skin(String nome, String url){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.url = url;
    }

    //getters

}
```

O método `getTest()` deverá retornar uma lista de Skins:

```
public List<Skin> getTest() {
    List<Skin> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome, imagem FROM skin", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(new Skin(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

O Adapter receberá essa lista no construtor e usá-la-á para popular as views de cada item da ListView:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Skins> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Skin> skins;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Skin> skins) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_picasso, skins);
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.Skins = skin;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_picasso, parent, false);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
        Skin skin = skins.get(position);

        txtTitle.setText(skin.getNome());
        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(skin.getUrl())
            .into(imageView);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Crie o adapter da seguinte forma:

```
....
....
DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).open();
List<Skins> skins = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getTest();
DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();

ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lista);
CustomAdapter adapter =  new CustomAdapter(this, skins);

listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
....
```

Comment: como na query retorna 2 strings pensei que so precisava dele. Como resolver os erros?

Comment: O campo image da tabela o que é?

Comment: uma string com a url da imagem

Comment: depois de quase 2 semanas tentando fazer isso vc resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Você está declarando o layout do item duas vezes.

O correto é só aqui:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_picasso, null,true);
```

Lá em cima na linha:

```
super(context, R.layout.list_picasso, nome);
```

Troca esse **R.layout.list_picasso** por **imagem**

ficando assim:

```
super(context, imagem, nome);
```

Comment: continua o mesmo erro com essa modificação.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua activity você está declarando o adapter com 2 parâmetros:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), names)
```

Já o seu contrutor tem possui 3 parâmetros:

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String nome, Integer imagem) { 
    super(context, R.layout.list_picasso, nome); 
 .....
}
```